# Is there a way to know the IMAP4 server's folder name of sent eMails?

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

In my Delphi 10 application i use tidIMAP4 to retrieve eMails with this (a portion of the) code

```
with IMAP4 do begin
case kind of
  1  : MsgBox := 'INBOX';
  10 : MsgBox := '[Gmail]/Sent Mail';//for GMail
  2  : MsgBox := '[Gmail]/Bin/Deleted Items';//for GMail
  3  : MsgBox := '[Gmail]/Spam';//for GMail
end;

SelectMailBox(MsgBox);
SetLength(SearchInfo, 1);
SearchInfo[0].Date := date-1;
SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skSince; 

if SearchMailBox(SearchInfo)
and (High(MailBox.SearchResult) > -1) then
            try
                msgs := High(MailBox.SearchResult)+1;
.....
```

I can find the mailboxes of the server with this code

```
var st : TstringList := TstringList.Create;
IMAP4.ListMailBoxes(st);
showmessage(st.Text);
st.Free;
```

so i can know the folder names that i must put in the `SelectMailBox(MsgBox)` function when i know the IMAP4 server a priori.

But i want a consistent way to know them for every server (yahoo, user's server etc)

Something like `SelectMailBox('deleted')` or similar.
Is this possible ?

Comment: Some servers support some subset of Special Use extensions (RFC 6154), in which case the LIST may return attribute \Trash.  Sometimes it may require a special parameter. And not all servers support it. Traditionally this was done by looking through the List response for a bunch of common names (Trash, Deleted, etc.). I have no idea how to access this through Delphi.

Comment: @Max. Thanks. I am thinking of presenting to the user the list of server folders and asking him to choose who will be assigned to each function. Is this practical?

Comment: The "Special Use" extension should be used when available by a server (check with `TIdIMAP4.IsCapabilityListed('SPECIAL-USE')`). However, `TIdIMAP4` does not currently support that extension: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/155

Comment: @max. Finally i used the solution you proposed ("by looking through the List response for a bunch of common names"). It solves my problem. Maybe you must post as an answer to upvote